# Targeting multiple class name when a button is clicked

Tags: jquery, button, input

```
$('.Btn1').on('click','.ass .exams .grade .total' function(r) {}
```

I tried to do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.Btn1').on('click','.ass .exams .grade .total' function(r) {
        r.preventDefault();
              var ass =   $('.ass').val();
              var exams = $('.exams').val();
              var grade = $('.grade').val();
              var total = $('.total').val();
              alert(ass + exams + grade + total);
      });

});
```

I want to get the values of these buttons when `.btn1` is clicked, to help me upload it into the database.

Comment: Please add what Programming Language your code is in as a tag. This makes your post more appealing to more advanced users of that programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using jQuery. You almost have the `click()` parameters correct:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('.Btn1').click(function(r) {
            r.preventDefault();

            var ass =   $('.ass').val();
            var exams = $('.exams').val();
            var grade = $('.grade').val();
            var total = $('.total').val();

            alert(ass + exams + grade + total);
      });

});
```

You could also use `console.log();` instead of an alert for debugging.